Kafka Connect - MongoDB Source Connector only processing 1 message
I am working on migrating some old kafka-connect clusters to new ones managed by Strimzi (this also includes upgrating kafka connect version 2.5->3.5).
Everything was going fine untill I got to the MongoDB connectors, for some reason the new connector only processes 1 message and then nothing, no logs, warnings or errors.
However this only happends in prod, while testing this in dev environment everything went as planned: created new connect cluster, created new connectors, ran both connectors simultaneously and checked metrics to make sure new connector is processing messages, and evetually pause & delete old connector & cluster, however like I mentioned in prod it processes a single message and then nothing.
I've compared config of both the connect cluster & the connector and there are no mistakes, both clusters use the same mongodb connector version (1.8), the only difference is the connect cluster version (existing clusrtes are 2.5 and new clusters are 3.5), however since I tested this in dev and didn't see any issues.
I've also checked mongodb logs but cannot find any errors or related warnings.
Here is the connect cluster & connector config for reference:
Cluster config:
config:
  group.id: '{{ include "kafka-connect.fullname" $ }}'

  config.providers: env
  config.providers.env.class: io.strimzi.kafka.EnvVarConfigProvider

  config.storage.topic: '{{ include "kafka-connect.fullname" $ }}-configs'
  offset.storage.topic: '{{ include "kafka-connect.fullname" $ }}-offsets'
  status.storage.topic: '{{ include "kafka-connect.fullname" $ }}-status'

  config.storage.replication.factor: '2'
  offset.storage.replication.factor: '2'
  status.storage.replication.factor: '2'

  key.converter: org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
  internal.key.converter: org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
  internal.value.converter: org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
  value.converter: io.confluent.connect.protobuf.ProtobufConverter
  value.converter.schema.registry.url: http://services-schema-registry:8081

  offset.flush.interval.ms: '10000'
  producer.buffer.memory: '33554432'
  producer.max.request.size: '60000000'

Connector config:
class: com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSourceConnector
tasksMax: 1
autoRestart:
  enabled: false
config:
  change.stream.full.document: updateLookup
  collection: my_collection
  connection.uri: ${env:MONGO_URL}
  copy.existing: false
  database: my_database
  heartbeat.interval.ms: 600000
  key.converter.schemas.enable: false
  key.converter: org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
  mongo.errors.tolerance: all
  output.format.key: schema
  output.format.value: schema
  output.schema.key: '...'
  output.schema.value: '...'
  value.converter.schemas.enable: false
  value.converter: org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter

